# Persisting cookies in Scrapy requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

#### What I want to scrape?

> Actually, I am trying to scrape a product website and gather some product information for every magasin. For that purpose I am using the necessary **POST** request to specify my magasin (get the corresponded cookies) and after that doing **GET** on my category. Scrapy have  already established a mechanism over sending requests with cookies. My problem is that in some of the time the requests in `parse` are made with the ***same cookies*** which is not what I want.
>
> > `parse_mag` that I created is just to check whether I am in a specific magasin

```
class BricoMarcheSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'brico_marche'

def start_requests(self):
    # full path 
    with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            # check empty value
            magasin_id = row['Id']
            if row['Id'][0] == '0':
                magasin_id = row['Id'][1:]
            formdata = {'city' : row['City'], 'market' : row['Brand'], 'idPdv' : magasin_id}
            #print(row['City'], row['Brand'], row['Id'])
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(url='http://www.bricomarche.com/bma_popin/Geolocalisation/choisirMagasin', formdata=formdata, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    yield scrapy.Request('http://www.bricomarche.com/l/nos-produits/jardin/abri-garage-carport-et-rangement/abri-de-jardin/les-abris-bois-1121.html?limit=90', dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse_mag)


def parse_mag(self, response):
    yield {"City" : response.xpath('//div[@class="store-details"]/p/strong/text()').extract_first()}
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `parse()` method always makes the exact same request to the same url, and `parse_mag()` gets called with the response.

So it's not that `parse_mag()` is called multiple times for a single POST request, it is called once per request, with the same arguments, returning the same result.

> Using https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:reqmeta-cookiejar

```
def start_requests(self):
    # full path 
    with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            # check empty value
            magasin_id = row['Id']
            if row['Id'][0] == '0':
                magasin_id = row['Id'][1:]
            formdata = {'city' : row['City'], 'market' : row['Brand'], 'idPdv' : magasin_id}
            #print(row['City'], row['Brand'], row['Id'])
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(url='http://www.bricomarche.com/bma_popin/Geolocalisation/choisirMagasin', formdata=formdata, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse, meta={'cookiejar': i})

def parse(self, response):
    yield scrapy.Request('http://www.bricomarche.com/l/nos-produits/jardin/abri-garage-carport-et-rangement/abri-de-jardin/les-abris-bois-1121.html?limit=90', dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse_mag, meta={'cookiejar': response.meta['cookiejar']})
```